# How can I set the UITableViewCellAccessory for a chosen row? (iPhone/iPad)

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

I need a way of setting the `UITableViewCellAccessory` for any row. However the catch is that I need to be able to do it OUTSIDE of the `UITableView` delegate methods.

I have tried this, but it doesn't show up the accessory.

```
[[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:1]] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
```

If it makes any difference I created the `UITableView` in IB in a storyboard. The data is static, and I'm using a grouped table style with only one section.

Please can someone help me out?

Comment: Can you reload the cell? Otherwise, you could try `setNeedsDisplay` but I'm not too confident it'll work.

Answer (score 3):

If your table view is scrolled so the cell in question may sometimes scroll out of view and then back into view, you should manage the content of that cell only from within the UITableView method `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. The reason is that when cells are redrawn, the tableview object calls this method to make sure that visible cells are properly rendered. (Cell that are not visible don't need to be rendered at all.)

That being said, this is where you should handle the cell content, even if the table view doesn't scroll the cell in question out of view. It wil lmake you life a lot easier if you follow this design pattern when working with table views.

Inside that method, you can test (using if statement, for example) the value of the indexPath.section and indexPath.row so that you can configure the specific cell the way you want it. This includes putting in the accessory.

Answer (score 2):

Always use `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:inSection:]` when working with table views.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I had just tried this but it didn't fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out what indexPath you need the checkmark on and then use something like this

```
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:someIndexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you suggestion. However I believe this is the same as what I already have...

Comment: Yeah, it's possible changing the accessory type on the fly doesn't work (until somebody says they've done it.) I know things like changing the edit accessory requires jumping through hoops to get it to take affect.