# addSubview to specific uitableviewcell on select

Tags: uitableview, addsubview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a tableview and I want to add an imageview to the contentView of the cell at the row it was selected in.

This is my current code and when I click any cell it only adds the imageView to the last row rather than the row I click on.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    playIcon = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 22, 9, 12)];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"cell_play.png"];
    [playIcon setImage:image];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:playIcon];
}
```

Comment: You don't show how `cell` is declared/initialized. I'd NSLog it to make sure it's valid ... Best to use `- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] addSubview:playIcon];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have not identified a cell at a particular row. Since your compiler didn't complain, I assume that cell is an ivar. It is pointing to the last cell that it was pointed to, which very well may be the last cell in the table.

You have to be careful that you don't set the content of a cell outside of the UITableview methods, including the UITableView method cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. This is described in a recent answer I provided [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038136/how-can-i-set-the-uitableviewcellaccessory-for-a-chosen-row-iphone-ipad/9038499#9038499).

So if you looked at that answer, you will have read that the tableview methods make sure the cell is rendered correctly even when the tableview scrolls and cells appear and disappear. I recommend that you set up your data source with some kind of tag or property that you can use to see that this image needs to be present. That way, it will be there even if you scroll the cell so it dissappears and reappears.

Comment: Sorry, but the "don't set the content of a cell outside of the UITableview methods" is just plain wrong. When talking about reloading a cell, the Apple docs say if you can just update the cell views, do that instead of a reload. Absolutely right that certain kinds of accessories (things that are not UIViews) don't necessarily get updated, but straightforward view hierarchy stuff should be fine.

Comment: I didn't say anything about doing a reload. The mechanisms that do a reload are independent of the point I was making. Putting cell updates into the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method (or through a method call originating there) assures that when cells are rendered, then the contents are rendered properly at the same time. This can happen as a consequence of the programmer's code explicitly calling one of the reload methods, but it also assures that rendering contents is correct when the user scrolls the table. This is because the tableView manages the need to reload cells.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was trying to reference the Apple docs but I couldn't put my finger on the hard reference: it's somewhere near where they talk about reloads (though I realize this isn't a reload case.) I was only trying to point out that a UITableViewCell is a UIView and that all normal UIView methods are fine on them.

Comment: No problem. If you are the one that down voted, can you undo it, then?

Comment: Sorry, but I think we still disagree. I think you're saying he shouldn't add a subview in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and that's entirely fine. Changing something like `editingAccessoryType` seems to be problematic, but adding a subview is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

work for me with UIcollectionView and UItableviewcell in Swift 2.0:

```
CV_Posts.cellForItemAtIndexPath(index)?.addSubview(imag_curtir)
```